# Aggregate Facebook posts and include app description

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I have noticed that posts from Seesmic & TripIt often aggregate & show a the app description + icon. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Aggregated Facebook stories posted via Seesmic API]

I'm posting messages to a users wall with the Graph API, but I'd like to know how to make the app description show up.

I have also tried posting a few feed stories successively but they are not aggregated like in the screenshot. Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not 100%, but I think that there's nothing you can do to force that, I believe that facebook decide when to aggregate stories and how. You can control aggregations with [Open Graph](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/).

Answer (score 1):

I am working with Facebook graph API right now and I can confirm that there is no method to group these posts.
This is something that Facebook does at its end to help the user manage the information.

Perhaps if you try to post multiple posts at frequent intervals, Facebook considers it a developing news activity coming from the same source and groups it together.

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented this for our client. This is called Facebook aggregation

Look here :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/defining-an-aggregation/